# sqlite copy .db file doesn't copy the last version of the file

Tags: sqlite, windows-10

I have a strange problem with my sqlite database.

In my sqlite database, I modified a table and added new columns.
I use SqliteStudio for this.

In visual studio, I use Entity Framework 6 and everything is ok.

On the same pc (and on other pcs) I have an older version of the database.

I simply copy the database file (myDb.db) from my development folder to program files on my pc or on another pc, I see the file size changes but when I connect to the database in the installation folder and open the changed table in SQliteStudio, I don't see newly created columns.

My OS is windows 10.

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is the database file open and being used by any programs when you copy it?

Comment: No, it is not used by any programs. And I don't have any error message. It copies but I don't see modifications.

Comment: Are you usin WAL mode? Do you have write access to "C:\Program Files"?

Comment: I don't know if it is on WAL mode, I didn't do anything for this. I just created an SQLite database via the SqliteStudio and created tables, views etc. I gave all rights to everyone on the installation folder in the program files.